# How to Use or Consume a Rest Server function

Tags: rest, delphi

It's my first time to deal with REST Server stuffs.I followed this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qt6hP5EzBME) and I was able to create a Rest Server. I was able to create a function `DoSomething` that queries our database and result a string. I was able to run the `Rest Server`, then `Open Browser`, and my function `DoSomething` is successfully resulting a value.
 Now, I want to use `DoSomething` in a separate application. I tried to follow this tutorial [link](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Tutorial:_Using_the_REST_Client_Library_to_Access_REST-based_Web_Services) but I can't comprehend the next steps after setting `TRestClient.BaseURL := http://localhost:8080`. Am I on the right track? How can I consume `DoSomething` in other application?

Comment: Just follow the instructions. That means from step 1. Step 1 says "Create a new project." Did you miss that step?

Comment: I did create a new project.. anyway I ended up creating a Web Service instead..